# Como usar el filtrado de AngularJS con Firebase

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase

Tengo un problema a la hora de que quiero filtrar un `array` de mi base de datos de `Firebase`, y es que a la hora de filtrar me sale el siguiente error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/unprp0=orderByPriorityFilterProvider%20%3C-""rderByPriorityFilter

de este código:

```html
<div class="row buscador_anime">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 columns">
            Filtrar Busqueda:
    <input type="text" ng-model="buscador">
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="resultado_anime">
   <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in firebase | orderByPriority | filter:buscador">
   <li><a href="{{ key }}">{{ value.titulo }}</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Ayudenme por favor, siento que tiene que ver con el Orderby pero no se en que

Comment: Lo solucione dando formato a lo que estoy filtrando es decir, dandole un $firebaseArray y resien dandole la busqueda con el firebaseArray, tambien quitandole el OrderByPriority, ya que ya no se usa xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El filtro `orderByPriority`  fue removido en el release 0.8 de AngularJS (Angular 1),

Los elementos se ordenan ahora por `priority` de forma predeterminada.

Elimina el filtro.

```
   <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in firebase | filter:buscador">
```